# Getting curved-based zooming speed?

Tags: c#, unity, mathematics

I am able to get a fairly smooth zooming function going on in my project.

However I'm hoping to achieve a non-linear function.

I've tried using the smoothstep function but it doesn't feel smooth (Could have been an improper implementation of mine).

If anyone can provide any suggestions, that will be greatly appreciated.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is that of the spectator camera, where it zooms in/out, in Dota2.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pan : MonoBehaviour {

    public float zoomSpeed = 20f;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3f;

    private float refSpeed = 0.0f;

    void Update () {

    if(Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            panUpdate();
        }

    if(Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            zoomUpdate();
        }

    }

    void panUpdate()
    {

    }

    void zoomUpdate()
    {

        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

//        float into = GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView + deltaMagnitudeDiff; //* ZoomSpeed

       // float smoothDiff = Mathf.SmoothDamp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, deltaMagnitudeDiff, ref zoomSpeed, smoothTime);


        // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
        GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * zoomSpeed, ref refSpeed, smoothTime);

        // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
        GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, 59.9f, 119.9f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float targetFieldOfView;
Camera currentCamera;

void Start() {
currentCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();
targetFieldOfView = currentCamera.fieldOfView;

}

void Update() {
    AdjustZoom();

}

void AdjustZoom() {
    if(Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);
        targetFieldOfView = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;
    }
    currentCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(currentCamera.fieldOfView, targetFieldOfView, Time.deltaTime * zoomSpeed);
}
```

Something like that will give you a nice zoom that starts off fast and slows down near the end. You can add an additional line in Update to check if currentCamera.fieldOfView is within a certain small amount of targetFieldOfView and skip calling AdjustZoom() if you want.

```
if(Mathf.Abs(currentCamera.fieldOfView - targetFieldOfView) > 0.01f)
    AdjustZoom()
```